# UIWebView, scrolling enabled but not bounces

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, uiscrollview

In my `UIWebView` I want to enable scrolling, but also disable the bounce effect (when I'm at the top and move my fingerdown and see a black block).

I tried a lot of combinations, but it seems that when I write:

```
myUIWebView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
```

this also disables scrolling entirely.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    for (id subview in myUIWebView.subviews) {
      if ([[subview class] isSubclassOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
        ((UIScrollView *)subview).bounces = NO;
      }
    }
```

As I know, that line, what you wrote, works only in iOS 5.0.

Comment: Thanks, that line works for me, with your code, I have the same effect, the bounce effect is disable, but it also the scroll. I suppose I missed something like :     webRent.scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES; but it doesn't work

Comment: Did you try to put the webRent.scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES; line after the bounce line?

Comment: I did it before and after, but it doesn't move

Comment: I know, that it's a pity, but you can even try to NSLog the webview's frame, and the webview.scrollview's frame too, just to see if the scrollview's frame is ok, or not.

Comment: I found a clue, what I have:     NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    [myUIWebView loadHTMLString:rentHTML baseURL:baseURL]; to add images from my project, but if I change baseURL to nil, it works, I cant see the relation!

Comment: Congrats :) Sincerely, I cannot see the relation too, but if it works, then it's ok.